# Mozilla Rhino JavaScript engine fails to compile(unable to locate a file in different directory)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rhino, commonjs

I have the Directory structure as below:

```
> com
> -javascript(Folder)
> --FileA.js(File)
> --subscript(Folder)
> ---FileB.js(File)
```

I want to access FileA inside FileB, I'm using CommonJS "Require" module to accomplish that as below.

```
inside FileB.js
var const = require("../FileA.js");
```

I am using Mozilla Rhino JavaScript engine to compile the javascript, I see below compilation error

```
Error :Java script error Module "../FileA" is not contained in sandbox.
```

I am not entirely sure, why this is happening any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to prevent a directory traversal attack. A) don't run the scripts from subfolders, but only those from the top folders B) look for a (command line?) argument to the engine that sets the sandbox directory.